# jQuery show / hide div on click not displayed correctly in Android and Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, show-hide

I have in Android and Chrome bad loads jQuery. When the page loads in Android and Chrome, whole menu is show and then hide. Without clicking. But I want to show the entire menu by clicking on the text "menu" or "menu 2". And it is correct only in Firefox.

Please, I have javascript code correctly?

And I want to ask whether possible create without jQuery or javascript? Without animation.

And the last question. Expand and collapse menu is jerky. Is possible somehow setting smoother sliding?

Thank you very much everyone for help and advice.

see here:     `<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/aw5xhdoq/" >jsfiddle.net/aw5xhdoq/</a>`

Comment: I opened the page in chrome and the menus are working as per your requirement, they are not showing fully then hiding. Maybe there was some delay in loading the script when you tried. As a workaround you can add `style="display:none;"` to your menus divs.

Comment: to inquizitive - wow, thank you very much. Simple but great. Once again, thank you, have a nice day.